# Comment "time ago" text indicates it is impossibly older than its parent question

Tags: bug, status-norepro, timestamps

I was reading [Javascript to download contents from a folder of webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818847/javascript-to-download-contents-from-a-folder-of-webpage), and I noticed a fault in the "time ago" system used to render "time elapsed" values.

[image: Impossible duration]

Obviously, I had not commented on the question before the question existed.

- Question post time: 2011-01-11 11:59:02Z
- Comment post time: 2011-01-11 11:59:53Z
- Time of observation: 2011-01-11 18:03:00-18:04:00-ish

The question timestamp changed to "6 hours ago" pretty swiftly thereafter.

Comment: Maybe it is implying that this person pre-emptively commented on a question he knew would come into existence. :o The universe works in mysterious ways!

Comment: @animuson: Although I am massively talented, I haven't cracked that one yet.

Comment: Strange. Did you notice if the page had any lag in rendering? The same code renders both of those "humanized" date formats.

Comment: Not noticeably as far as I can recall. Certainly nothing of up to four minutes in duration! Strange one

Answer (score 4):

At a guess, the question and the comments have their own caches and you just got the result of the question cache being a bit stale.

Either that, or it is a new time warp feature on comments.

Comment: "Time ago" is generated in cache? Wouldn't that be a bit daft? Note that the timestamps themselves are (a) probably accurate, and (b) never change. Just whatever translates those values into a "human-readable duration" is buggy at certain times...

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - Actually, I think a time warp feature would be awesome (and the SO guys are the ones that can do it!)

Comment: Perhaps they could invent something to time warp me back to before I ever set foot on SO, and warn myself not to do it... _before it was too late_

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - Another option is that this is done client side and for some reason the JS got to the comment markup first and then got a good long delay before getting to the question.

Comment: I witnessed no four-minute delays in the page rendering. (Also, it's not.)

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: It's me. Reasoning is above. I do not believe that this could be the cause.